# Android ImageView getting over linearlayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing an android application, The layout is shown in the image below :

[Screenshot http://www.lebanon-trading-center.com/daymanager/layout.PNG](http://www.lebanon-trading-center.com/daymanager/layout.PNG)

The layout contains 2 main linearlayouts : a horizontal layout that takes 90% of the height of the device and a vertical layout that takes 10% of it. Inside the horizontal linearlayout there is three linearlayout ( two red and one containing an imageview). Each red layout is 10% of the width of the screen and the one containing the ImageView is 80%. Here is the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:weightSum="1"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#ff0000" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.8" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#ff0000"  >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, when I set a PNG image (1036px X 730px ) as a source to the ImageView, the ImageView will get over the bottom linearlayout ( the black one ) and the two red layouts will be squeezed.

[Screenshot http://www.lebanon-trading-center.com/daymanager/layout2.PNG](http://www.lebanon-trading-center.com/daymanager/layout2.PNG)

My question is how can I solve the problem and have the same layouts functional on all kind of tablets ?

Comment: can you post an Image of the layout where when you set the png image (1036px X 730px )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.90">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:background="#ff0000" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.80" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:background="#ff0000"  >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, can I work it around so that the picture won't be stretched ?

Comment: Sure, replace this : android:scaleType="fitXY" with this: android:adjustViewBounds="true" to ImageView

Comment: @user3012088 FYI nested weights are bad for performance. But I think there is no other choice :)